# Create a rectangle region mask on image with OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision

There are a image that read in `cv::Mat` format and I only want to remain a rectangle region to be detect in the center of image. I tried the `cvCopy` approach, but it required the image format as `cvArr` and does any guys have any idea how to implement that still use `Mat` format as well?

---

There is my code and screenshot for creating a mask and it seems strange that the size of mask did not match with the original frame. Any tips here please?

```
    *cap >> frame1;
    Rect roi(100,100,100,100);
    for(int i =0; i<frame1.rows; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<frame1.cols;j++)
        {
            if(!roi.contains(Point(i,j)))
            {
                frame1.at<uchar>(i,j) = 0;
            }
        }
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply create new image, that refers to same data.

```
cv::Rect const mask(x1, y1, x2, y2);
cv::Mat roi = image(mask);
```

Now you can do *roi* processing. All changes on roi will appply on image too.

Comment: i am trying to make the mask of eclipse but this function is showing error while i make its object like `ellipse const mask(img,Point(20,40), Size(60,40),0,0,360, Scalar(0,0,0));`

Comment: Hi, Ahmad. Sorry, but this information is not enough to help you. Please, create a new question and provide more details.